# How to build -dev package in launchpad?

Tags: apt, package-management, compiling, ppa, launchpad

I am developing small library and I've created appropriate debian package configuration. You can take a look at it at https://github.com/mspanc/vspec.

When I run `debuild` locally it properly builds main binary package as well as -dev and -dbg counterparts.

When I sync it with Launchpad in order to automatically make builds & PPA, only the main binary package is build (see https://code.launchpad.net/~mspanc/+recipe/vspec-unstable).

What is the reason for different behaviour of launchpad than default debian/ubuntu build tools?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your control file, I see that you have the first dependency on the next line.

```
Depends:
 libvspec-1.0-0 (= ${binary:Version}),
 ${misc:Depends}
```

I would suggest you put that on the same line (like the main binary):

```
Depends: libvspec-1.0-0 (= ${binary:Version}), ${misc:Depends}
```

And try a build again.

It works for me and I have things on the same line, but I'm pretty sure I've had some such issues before. (i.e. there is something about having things on the very first line or not)